# carrying out a Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: r

I'm analyzing the data set `data(wine)` from the R package `gclus`.

I split the data set according to the proportions `70:30` into a training and a test set.

```
library(gclus)
data("wine")
sample_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(wine))
set.seed(123)
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(wine)), size = sample_size)
train <- wine[train_index, ]
test <- wine[-train_index, ]
```

How could I now carry out  LDA for the following data subsets:

1. `wine[c("Class", "Ash", "OD280", "Nonflavanoid")]`
2. `wine[c("Class", "Hue", "Magnesium", "Flavanoids", "Alcohol", "Malic", "Intensity", "Alcalinity", "Proline")]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `lda` in `MASS` package:

```
MASS::lda(Class~Ash+OD280+Nonflavanoid, train)
Call:
lda(Class ~ Ash + OD280 + Nonflavanoid, data = train)

Prior probabilities of groups:
        1         2         3 
0.3225806 0.3790323 0.2983871 

Group means:
       Ash    OD280 Nonflavanoid
1 2.487500 3.163250    0.2950000
2 2.255106 2.766809    0.3727660
3 2.456486 1.714865    0.4575676

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
                    LD1       LD2
Ash           0.8918665  3.862102
OD280        -2.3406276 -0.482271
Nonflavanoid  1.2410102 -5.865365

Proportion of trace:
   LD1    LD2 
0.8966 0.1034
```

You can do the same for the second case

Comment: Thank a lot @onyambu. How could I visualize the results?

Comment: @SarahB Do you want to visualize the results or the linear discriminant planes? you have 3 dimensions probably a 3d plot? Am not sure with that. You might consider asking a question on how to visualize the results of `lda`. But if you want to visualize the different classes, you can use `predict` to predict the classes and plot them , ie `a <- MASS::lda(...); b<- predict(a); plot(b$x, col = b$class)`

Comment: yes, I want to make use of the function predict to predict the class memberships for the test data, and compare the predictions with the true class memberships.

Comment: @SarahB i just gave you the code. just do `predict(your_model)$class`